# Submit Button Javascript Causing Form To Not Submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a Signup Form that I've used JS to divide into three separate fieldsets. I've also written a JS function for the actual handling of the form data. The form itself looks great, and the Previous and Next buttons work fine, but the Submit Button just presses and is not Submitting. Is the problem in the signup() function?

The Form is as follows:

```
<body>
<!-- multistep form -->

<form id="signupform">
    <!-- progressbar -->


    <ul id="progressbar">

        <li class="active">Personal Profile</li>

        <li>Second Profile</li>

        <li>Additional Details</li>

   </ul>


<!-- fieldsets -->


<fieldset>

    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>

    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>

    <input type="text" id="username" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="100" placeholder="Username" />
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
        <input type="text" id="email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="password" id="pass1" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100" placeholder="Password" />
        <input type="password" id="pass2" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="100" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />

</fieldset>


<fieldset>

    <h2 class="fs-title">Second Profile</h2>

    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">The Second You</h3>


    <select id="favorite genre" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" placeholder="Favorite Genre" />
            <?php include("template_genre_list.php"); ?>
        </select>

        <select id="second favorite genre" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" placeholder="Second Favorite Genre" />
            <?php include("template_genre_list.php"); ?>
        </select>

    <select id="tfg" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" placeholder="Third Favorite Genre" />
            <?php include("template_genre_list.php"); ?>
        </select>

    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />

</fieldset>


<fieldset>

    <h2 class="fs-title">Additional Details</h2>

    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">The Additional Things</h3>


    <select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" placeholder="Gender" />
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>

    <select id="state" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" placeholder="State" />
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
            <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
            <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
            <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
            <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
            <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
            <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
            <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
            <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
            <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
            <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
            <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
            <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="New York">New York</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
            <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
            <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
            <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
            <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
            <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
            <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
            <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
        </select>

    <input type="text" id="city" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('city')" maxlength="200" placeholder="City (or General Location)">

    <input id="biography" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('biography')" maxlength="200" placeholder="A Short But Awesome Bio" />

    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />

    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>

    <span id="status"></span>

</fieldset>

</form>

<!-- jQuery -->


<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script src="signupjs/signup.js"></script>

</body>
```

and the signup() function is as follows:

```
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var sta = _("state").value;
    var cit = _("city").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var bio = _("biography").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || sta == "" || cit == "" || g == "" || bio == ""){
    status.innerHTML = "Please fill out all the fields! ";
} else if(p1 != p2){
    status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
} else {
    _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
    status.innerHTML = 'Please Wait ...';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&sta="+sta+"&cit="+cit+"&c="+c+"&g="+g+"&pi="+pi+"&si="+si+"&ai="+ai+"&fg="+fg+"&sfg="+sfg+"&tfg="+tfg+"&fa="+fa+"&hi="+hi+"&av="+av+"&bio="+bio);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you notice in your console if any errors are being thrown from the `signup` function?

Comment: I'd suggest using JSFiddle and create the simplest code sample first to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using event.preventDefault(); in your signup() function?
This would prevent the default handling of buttons, which may solve your problem.